# How to make video player only use up to 50percent of the screen height?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

My video player is wrapped in the aspect ratio widget and everything works fine when the videos are in landscape mode but when there's a video in portrait mode, it takes the whole screen. (most of the time, it will also overflow the screen) I only want the video player take up to half the screen max. So I figure I wrap aspect ratio with a constrainedbox and set max height to some number but that just messes up the layout even more. Can someone help me please.

Comment: I think MediaQuery might help you with that. Can you please share your code so we can be of better help?

Answer (score 0):

Use [media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/orientation) to specify orientation and [vh](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) unit to define height

```
@media (orientation: portrait) {
  .widget {
    height: 50vh;
  }
}
```